# Cyclic direct summands over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given R a PID and a an element of R. What is the largest number of non-trivial cyclic direct summands one can decompose R/(a) into?

Comment: It's unbounded? For example, $\mathbb{Z}/(p_1\cdots p_n)$ has $n$ factors.

Comment: would u be able to construct a direct sum of two cyclic such as 2 and 3 since they're not necessarily disjoint?